# FB og:image getting recognized but not showing up FB:like

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Currently I am implementing a fb like with image og:image with it.  If you go to the link of the debug you will find out that the picture works.  I can get the picture recognized but it's not showing up on the debug or when liking it.  Do you have any suggestions?  The website is https://www.mansettispizza-hamlake.com for the open-graph meta data.  I know the site doesn't valid for the w3c but that shouldn't be causing any issues.  I tried switching it to jpg as well and using  link rel="image_src" as well.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mansettispizza-hamlake.com

https://www.mansettispizza-hamlake.com/wp-content/themes/wisewordsfromwoo/images/Mansettis.png

I tried to switch it to 
https://www.mansettispizza-hamlake.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/house-special-pizza-mansettis-pizza-best-pizza-blaine-pizza-chanticlear-broadway-150x150.jpg

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude, but researching your issue is making me hungry. ;-) So far I cannot find anything out of the norm, just like the debugger tool doesn't...other than not showing the image.

Comment: lol yeah I don't know maybe is it the ssl??  I'm confused.

Comment: As much as I would like to blame it on https, this is a case where I don't think it matters.  (Some people can't understand why their users can't see a facebook app that doesn't have the https urls in them when the user has https only specified.  LOL)

Comment: Could it possibly be that it takes awhile for fb to render the image as a thumbnail?

Comment: I see that fb does a safe_image over the image http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQA6cp7M3uTsciV5&url= MY URL and when clicking on that it doesn't get anything.  So maybe FB has to render my image in their cache or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove SSL and it will work! I had the same problem and just resolved it by throwing away SSL.

Comment: Even with a SSL redirect or should I just house my images on a none secured hosting area.

Comment: My images are now hosted without SSL. I didn't try any redirecting.